# To get event corresponding to page load time in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters, google-analytics-firebase

I want to track page load time using google analytics. I have a single page application . In order to track i added the given script inside head tag . And in order to get page load time , i added the second script just before the body tag but unfortunately i am not able to find any event in Google Analytics corresponding to this .  It seems like this gtag() is not executing somehow. Can someone please help out. Also where do we see event_value in Google analytics. I am able to find event_category and event_action by going into RealTime->Events but i can't find any event_value there.

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

```js
<script>
    if(window.performance){
        // Gets the number of milliseconds since page load
        // (and rounds the result since the value must be an integer).
        var timeSincePageLoad = Math.round(performance.now());
        // Sends the timing event to Google Analytics.
        gtag('event', 'timing_complete', {
        'name': 'load',
        'event_value': timeSincePageLoad,
        'event_category': 'Home page loading time'
       });
    }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-timings) it should be *value*, not *event_value*

```
  gtag('event', 'timing_complete', {
    'name': 'load',
    'value': timeSincePageLoad,
    'event_category': 'Home page loading time'
  });
```